# How to access a Viewpager's Fragment method?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

I have a nested Fragment with a Viewpager inside of it. I'm trying to access a method (using MainActivity) in one of the Viewpager's Fragments, but I only get the last Viewpager Fragment or can't access methods when I use

```
ProfileFragment f = (ProfileFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentLayout);
...
Fragment f = v.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager);

// Doesn't even work when I use findFragmentByTag("TAG")
```

where 'fragmentLayout' is the container for my Fragment Transactions inside activity_main.xml. (Currently ProfileFragment inside)

Here is how I nested my Fragments/xml:

```
MainActivity
  - fragmentLayout
    - ProfileFragment (or LoginFragment/ChatFragment/ShopFragment/etc)
      - xml items
      - viewPager
        - Fragment1
        - Fragment2 // can't access methods in here from MainActivity
  - navigationTabs
```

I tried getting the Viewpager & PageAdapter from ProfileFragment and it shows the correct number of fragments, but I can't seem to access the methods.

Would an interface be something to look into? Or is there an easier way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the solutions worked for me & I had trouble implementing an interface with my nested fragments.

I ended up putting the methods in MainActivity which was the easiest solution for me.

I can also access the nested fragment views directly from MainActivity with

```
TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.exampleid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String tag = makeFragmentName(mViewPager.getId(), getItemId(position));
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
return fragment;
((YourFragment)fragment).methodName();
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 simple ways to do it:

1. Store your `Fragment1` and `Fragment2` in your `ProfileFragment`, then when you need to call there's function, just call `fragment1.doSomeThing()` from your `ProfileFragment`. This approach is ok when your `ViewPager's adapter` dont have too many fragments (in this case, you should use `WeakReference` to avoid OOM when storing your fragments`.
2. Using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) (or `LocalBroadCastReceiver`, but I prefer `EventBus`). Then you can call your `doSomeThing()` function from anywhere, with the call like below:

   `EventBus.getDefault().post(new CallYourFunctionObject(int value)`